# Open Editform.aspx when clicking on New Button - SharePoint Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint

Good day,

I am working on Office 365: SharePoint online.

I am trying to do the following: I have a library with a custom content type with many columns. Also have a template attached to this content type.

When users click the New Button on the library I want the editform.aspx to be completed before the template opens. So in other words the metadata should be completed 1st before content be added to the new document(template).

I have javascirpt that is executing on the Presave function when on editform, so word quick parts or information panel wont work. I this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible thru the UI as far as I know.  But if you are using Quickparts you can edit those directly in Microsoft Word, and they should save back when the document is saved.

You could create a custom page to handle all this but then you have to programmatic create the new item, populate values, and then open the document for the user.